# PHP: I cant send an email to multiple recipients

Tags: php, email

I've checked php manual, but still can't get my script to work

If I delete the BCC line, the mail goes to $to1 but with BCC line, it goes nowhere

here is the code:

```
// email stuff
$to1 = "address1@mail.com";
$to2 = "address2@mail.com";
$from = "noreply@mail.com"; 
$subject = "Subject"; 
$message = "message";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// main header
$headers  = "To: ".$to1.$eol;
$headers .= "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "Bcc: ".$to2.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol;

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// send message
mail($to1, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

If anyone has an idea, thanks a lot

Comment: Apparently some servers kill outgoing email containing CC and BCC as mentioned here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#89043 It might be worth checking your config.

Comment: I believe the problem comes from my webhost because even without bcc, if I set $to1 = "address1@mail.com, address2@mail.com" it still doesn't work

Comment: Use an SMTP server, instead of the webhoster's MTA.

Comment: Thanks diggersworld & Bart Friederichs for your help, it was finally a problem with the recipient mail server (yopmail) which I guess automatically delete duplicate mails, so it's ok with any other mail provider